# UIPopoverController for iPad "must not be called with `nil`" error

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to make an iPhone app work in an iPad but the UIPopoverController is
comming back with error.

```
- (IBAction)photoTapped1 {
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
// If in editing state, then display an image picker; if not, create and push a photo view controller.
    if (self.editing) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        [imagePicker release];
    } else {
        RecipePhotoViewController *recipePhotoViewController = [[RecipePhotoViewController alloc] init];
        recipePhotoViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        recipePhotoViewController.recipe = recipe;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:recipePhotoViewController animated:YES];
        [recipePhotoViewController release];
    }
}else{
    if (self.editing){
        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popover];
        self.popover.delegate =self;
        [popover release];
    }else{
         RecipePhotoViewController *recipePhotoViewController = [[RecipePhotoViewController alloc] init];
         recipePhotoViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
         recipePhotoViewController.recipe = recipe;
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:recipePhotoViewController animated:YES];
         [recipePhotoViewController release];
    }}}
```

The error I am getting is: 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] must not be called with `nil`.'

Anyone available to give me a hand on this code, I have looked on the internet for solutions and samples but can not seem to make it work.

Thank you.

___ *added to original question****_*____**

I am adding the recipePhotoViewController here, I am assuming that ImageView manipulation is the same for iPhone and iPad.

my.h File

```
@class Recipe;

@interface RecipePhotoViewController : UIViewController {
@private
    Recipe *recipe;
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) Recipe *recipe;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

Here is my .m file

```
@implementation RecipePhotoViewController

@synthesize recipe;
@synthesize imageView;

- (void)loadView {
self.title = @"Photo";

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

self.view = imageView;   }
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
imageView.image = [recipe.image valueForKey:@"image"];}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation  {
 return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
- (void)dealloc {
[imageView release];
[recipe release];
[super dealloc];
}   @end
```

Comment: check `popover` variable - it's nil

Comment: self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popover]; In side popover you ar try same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the popover controller in a wrong way:

```
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popover];
```

You should pass the controller you would like to display inside of the popover -- not the popover itself (which is `nil` since you have not yet initialised it)!

Maybe this would do it for you?

```
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
```

If this is correct, then you should also **present** the pop over you have just created: [– presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/presentPopoverFromRect%3ainView%3apermittedArrowDirections%3aanimated%3a)

-- e.g.:

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

where `sender` is the argument to :

```
- (IBAction)photoTapped1:(id)sender {
```

Comment: Thank you, That is how I had the code before I changed it an nothings happen, when I click on my edit button and tap on the image does nothing and I do not get any error.

Comment: Thank you sergio, that was very help full and it is working now. I am able to change the image now. the sender argument was crashing the my iPhone so I left the -(IBAction)photoTapped1 as it is, without the (id)sender.

Answer (score 1):

The *content* of your popover which you store in the variable `popover` is obviously `nil`. I can't see it ever being created in the code you provided.

Maybe you intended to present the Recipe photo controller as the content of the popover. In that case you would do something like

```
RecipePhotoViewController *recipePhotoViewController = [[RecipePhotoViewController alloc] init];
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:recipePhotoViewController];
```

Comment: Thank you David, I changed it an nothings happen, when I click on my edit button and tap on the image does nothing and I do not get any error.

Comment: @Derek well, what are you trying to present inside the popover? *That* is what should be the content view controller.

Comment: Hi, I am using the core data recipe sample from apple, This Item is a photo for the recipe, The data already contain sample recipes with some images and when I click on edit, I am supposed to be able to tap on the recipe photo and change it with another image stored on my phone or iPad images.

Comment: I have added the RecipePhotoViewController to the original question, I am assuming that imageView handling is the same for iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 0):

problem is in this line of your code ,

```
    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popover];
```

try like this

```
    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
            UIView*   popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 320, 260)];
        popoverContent.view = popoverView;
//Add what ever you want popoverView

 self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
        self.popover.delegate =self;
```

Comment: Thank you, I have try all the above options but when I click on the edit button and tab on the image nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you, the iPhone code works great and that is what I am trying to replicate but for the iPad. Any other suggestions are appreciated.